# Superhero cartoon where a blue-and-white alien combines with the hero

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, super-hero

It was a superhero cartoon.
The main character I think finds an alien which is white and blue then the alien combines with the main character. The main character's father was working with the alien, and the main character later finds this out.

His suit is white and blue and it has four side villain that were Elementals.
There was one big villain, I think his color scheme was black and red

This cartoon used to be on Netflix and there might have been a movie about it, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 6):

This could be [*Max Steel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Steel_(2013_TV_series)) (the newest 2013 series, not the 2000 one with the same name).

[image: Max (the boy) and Steel]

The linked Wikipedia page states (emphasis added):

> A 16-year-old boy named "Maxwell McGrath" is thrown into a new life when he and his mom moved to a small town called Copper Canyon. There he meets new friends, bullies, enemies, and a lot more. But later he starts to generate a powerful blue energy called "T.U.R.B.O. Energy". Max must now join N-Tek, a top secret organization his father worked on and meets a friendly ultralink named N'Barro Aksteel X377/Steel. When sinister super villains attack Copper Canyon, **Max and Steel must link together and transform into a powerful Superhero** named "Max Steel!".

The "alien" is called an **Ultralink** (having seen very little of this, I don't know whether the Ultralinks are really aliens or robots or something else ...).

The same page cites *"Elementors (Fire Elementor, Earth Elementor, Water Elementor, Air Elementor, and Metal Elementor)"*, that could be the element-based villains you remember.

The superhero wears a white and light blue (and black) suit, images returned from a Google search show a larger, red and black guy who could be a villain.

The series ran for two seasons (the second one first airing on Netflix) and several tv movies, from 2013 to 2017.

---

<sub>How I found this out: at the time I watched a few fragments of this cartoon, but I could not now remember its name; after a few failed Google searches, I remembered there was an associated toy line and I arrived at the [*"Television series by Mattel Creations"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Television_series_by_Mattel_Creations) Wikipedia page, and thence at this title.</sub>

Comment: At the beginning of this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTWYdhVuaos) you can see the "transformation sequence" where Max and Steel combine.

Answer (score -1):

TrollHunter? Arcadia series. Perhaps. Was one of the finest ever made.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] in some details about the show, the hero, and the alien in question?  Images or screenshots would be helpful too.  Look at the existing answer as an example.